# how to get and use the index of each list member

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have seen some posts similar to this, but none saved and used it in the way I am trying to do. The method below receives lists of varying sizes, and I want to be able to prompt the user to choose which list member they like to invoke, and then invoke that member. The only way I know of doing that is by using the index of that member in the list.

```
    private static void LoadAssemAndShowPublicTypes(String assemId)
    {
        //Explicitly load an assembly into this domain
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(assemId);
        //Execute this loop once for each type 
        //Publicly exported from the loaded assembly 
        List<Type> currentAssemblyTypes = new List<Type>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Type t in a.ExportedTypes)
        {
            //Display the full name of the type
            currentAssemblyTypes.Add(t);
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} - {t.FullName}");
            i++;
        }
        foreach (var t in currentAssemblyTypes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} - {t.FullName}");
            Console.WriteLine("Which one(s) would you like to Invoke?");
            String userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            List<string> userChoices = new List<string>();
            userChoices.Add(userChoice);
            // pass the member(s) of currentAssemblyType that corresponds to the number(s) user chose 
            // to InvokeTypesRequested() method
        }
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void InvokeTypesRequested(List<Type> requestedTypes)
    {

    }
```

I managed to getaway with "i ", but I do not see how that is going to work for me if I want to use the second member of the currentAssemblyTypes in a different method to Invoke it. So if the second member is myClass, I want to invoke that class, and then proceed to interact with the user to access myClass's types. I am only talking about the index since that is the only way I can think of accomplishing this. I am assuming there is a LINQ statement that would work for me. Just not sure how. I updated the code above; hopefully it provides more context on what I am trying to do. Thank you so much.

Comment: I really didnt understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Question is unclear.. What are you trying to do? Do you want to access an item in a list by an index? Do you want to access that list from a different method?

Comment: Perhaps you want to store all the types in a `Dictionary<int,Type>` so you can easily go back and look up a type by its index?

Comment: @Jamiec could be but it seems like the integer is merely a running index - and if that is the case then no need for a dictionary and just `list[i]`

Comment: I'm unclear what is being asked here, and unclear why I'm the only person so far to vote it to be close as unclear!

Comment: I am so sorry; I'll update to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not really much clearer. What does "invoke that class" mean? Create an instance of it? Still not clear why you think you need LINQ

Comment: @ Jamiec- I want to create an instance of that class. I want to pass it to another method so that method can create an instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really hard to tell from your code what you are trying accomplish, but it would appear that you are looking for `Activator`. But without an interface or further reflection, all your are going to get is an instance of the class without knowing what functions are available in that instance.  That said the code below will set `obj` to an instance of the requested class from the assembly name passed to LoadAssemAndShowPublicTypes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadAssemAndShowPublicTypes("Assembly Name Here");
    }

    private static void LoadAssemAndShowPublicTypes(String assemId)
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(assemId);
        List<Type> currentAssemblyTypes = new List<Type>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Type t in a.ExportedTypes)
        {
            currentAssemblyTypes.Add(t);
            Console.WriteLine($"{++i} - {t.FullName}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Which one(s) would you like to Invoke?");
        String userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userChoice != "0")
        {
            CreateInstance(currentAssemblyTypes[Convert.ToInt32(userChoice) - 1]);
        }
    }

    private static void CreateInstance(Type requestedType)
    {
        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(requestedType);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was after. Thank you so much.